# profiling the jvm where most garbage is generated and what type it has, escape analysis optimization

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm, profiling, escape-analysis

I know that my program invokes the gc in regular intelvals, but I would like to analyse only the generated garbage. I want to know which classes are most frequently abandoned, and much more important, where are those instances created. Generally I want to optimize for escape analysis to reduce the garbage collection to a minimum.

Edit:
I am not interested in live objects.

Comment: are you working in some sort of real-time system where minimizing gc delays is critical?

Comment: This question shows how to get counts of live objects by type: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8126868/profiling-number-of-garbage-collected-object-instances-per-class

Comment: Here's another one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8923689/java-garbage-collector-get-the-deleted-objects

Comment: @jtahlborn if 60 fps is real-time, then yes it is some sort of a real-time system ;). But also very important for me is that I can decrease the maximum heap size when less garbage is generated.

Comment: @LeeMeador thanks for the link, the second link looked promising, but it doesn't give me statistics about dead objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JProfiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html) gives you statistics about garbage collected objects. The allocation tree and hot spots even show you where they have been created.

In the "Recorded objects" view, change the "Liveness mode" to "Garbage collected objects":

[image]

Disclaimer: My company develops JProfiler.